# Spring Batch correct way to break down existing large ItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am currently looking at refactoring an existing Spring Batch job.

The reader however appears to be too manipulating too much data.

One read currently

- Goes to an external service for a list of objects
- Uses this list to go to another service to populate a map
- Then use this map to query a further service twice
- Use the result to create the object used to write to a CSV

am i correct in thinking that this hampers spring batches ability to chunk the job efficiently?

I believe that a better way to do this is to have the read only do the first step above and then have the further steps be handled by a composite processor.

Is this the best way to handle this job or is there a smarter way to use multiple steps or multiple reads to handle this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that the `ItemReader` (by your description) is probably doing too much.  The driving query pattern would apply here and indicates that from the `ItemReader` you would want to return items and then use an `ItemProcessor` to enrich or transform them.  You may need to do some aggregation to handle performance impacts of calling those other remote services but you can handle that without coupling all of that logic into the `ItemReader`.

You can read more about the driving query pattern in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders

Comment: Thanks for your response.

So you are saying with this driving query pattern that only the values required in the proceeding processor should be fetched, so avoid SELECT * if only 3 of 5 columns are required for example?

Comment: It's a balance.  If you are going to need the extra data from the `SELECT *` later, it's a better idea to get it all at once than doing a `SELECT ID, A, B FROM FOO` to only later in the `ItemProcessor` also do `SELECT C, D, E FROM FOO WHERE ID = ?`.

Comment: Perfect thanks. 

Think this is the right way to go based on what i have been able to accomplish so far.

Comment: What is the correct way to go about adding a JdbcCursorItemReader to a composite ItemProcessor. 

Is this possible or will a custom ItemProcessor be required.